# I have been getting this error for my code and don't know whats wrong with it

Tags: sql

the error I get says unknown column 'CLUB.CLUB_NAME' in 'field list' here is my script:

```
SELECT CLUB.Club_NAME AS 'Club',TEAM.TEAM_NAME AS 'Team',TEAM.BIRTH_YEAR AS'Year of Birth'
FROM SEASON
JOIN DIVISION ON
DIVISION.SEASON_ID = SEASON.SEASON_ID
JOIN ASSIGNMENT ON 
ASSIGNMENT.DIVISION_ID = DIVISION.DIVISION_ID
JOIN TEAM ON
TEAM.TEAM_ID = ASSIGNMENT.TEAM_ID
WHERE SEASON.SEASON_TYPE = 'Spring' AND Year(SEASON.SEA_START) = '2019' AND DIVISION.AGE <= '12'
```

this is my tables with the columns:

```
SHOW TABLES;
CREATE TABLE SEASON(SEASON_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
SEASON_TYPE varchar(6) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
REG_START DATE NOT NULL,
REG_END DATE NOT NULL,
SEA_START DATE NOT NULL,
SEA_END DATE NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE DIVISION(DIVISION_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
AGE VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
GENDER VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
EMAIL VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
PHONE CHAR(12) NOT NULL,
RANKING INT NOT NULL,
SEASON_ID INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (SEASON_ID) REFERENCES SEASON(SEASON_ID));

CREATE TABLE CLUB(CLUB_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
CLUB_NAME VARCHAR(22) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
EMAIL VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PHONE CHAR(12) NOT NULL,
ABBREVIATION VARCHAR(5) NULL);

CREATE TABLE TEAM(TEAM_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
TEAM_NAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
BIRTH_YEAR INT NOT NULL,
GENDER VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
PHONE CHAR(12) NOT NULL,
EMAIL VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
CLUB_ID INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (CLUB_ID) REFERENCES CLUB(CLUB_ID));

CREATE TABLE ASSIGNMENT( DIVISION_ID INT NOT NULL ,TEAM_ID INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (DIVISION_ID) REFERENCES DIVISION(DIVISION_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (TEAM_ID) REFERENCES TEAM(TEAM_ID));

SHOW TABLES;

DESCRIBE SEASON;
 
DESCRIBE DIVISION;

DESCRIBE ASSIGNMENT;

DESCRIBE TEAM;

DESCRIBE CLUB;
```

Comment: i accidentally added the script two times  their both the same

Comment: there is no table club in   your from clause, so the column Club_NAME is not known

Comment: @sameerawafa you can edit the question to update it yourself

Comment: So do I delete the from division add from club or do I use both from division, club.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'd recommend reading the [how to ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The title of this post can be much improved.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join all tables, if you want to get the content of a column, so JOIN CLUB

The query will look like

```
SELECT CLUB.Club_NAME AS 'Club',TEAM.TEAM_NAME AS 'Team',TEAM.BIRTH_YEAR AS'Year of Birth'
FROM SEASON
JOIN DIVISION ON
DIVISION.SEASON_ID = SEASON.SEASON_ID
JOIN ASSIGNMENT ON 
ASSIGNMENT.DIVISION_ID = DIVISION.DIVISION_ID
JOIN TEAM ON
TEAM.TEAM_ID = ASSIGNMENT.TEAM_ID
JOIN CLUB
ON CLUB.CLUB_ID = TEAM.CLUB_ID 
WHERE SEASON.SEASON_TYPE = 'Spring' AND Year(SEASON.SEA_START) = '2019' AND DIVISION.AGE <= '12'
```

Comment: so looks like the code went through successfully but there is no data showing

Comment: first run the code without where and see if it has results, then add one where clause after another and see in very step if results are shown

Comment: so looks like in the first and second clause their is data shown but when I add the last clause it is empty and their is no data only the columns show.

Comment: all conditions have to be true, if one of your conditions is false no rows are returned as no row full fills all conditions